# Best way to rewrite a WHERE NOT IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got a query like the one below:

```
Select ser.key
From dbo.Enrlmt ser     
Where ser.wd >= @FromDate AND ser.wd <= @ThrouDate AND
      ser.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321' AND
      ser.StuExitCatgCode in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7') AND
      ser.Key not in (select Key 
                           from Enrlmt ser2 
                          where ser2.StartDate <= @AsOfDate 
                            AND ser2.StartDate > ser.wd 
                            AND ser2.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321')
```

That is extremely slow due to the "NOT IN" clause.  I tried rewriting it using a left outer join so that it looked like:

```
   Select ser.key
     From dbo.Enrlmt ser    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Enrlmt ser2 ON ser.key = ser2.key
                         AND ser2.StartDate <= @AsOfDate 
                         AND ser2.StartDate > ser.wd 
                         AND ser2.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321'
   Where ser2.key is null
     AND ser.wd >= @FromDate 
     AND ser.wd <= @ThrouDate 
     AND ser.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321' 
     AND ser.StuExitCatgCode in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

Which is much faster but the results don't match up.  Am i doing something wrong with this rewrite?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 'NOT IN' is not slow - it's because you're using a correlated subquery.

Comment: The NOT IN is *not* causing your performance issue, assuming the columns are not nullable: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: Searching for numbers as strings makes me cringe too

Comment: Codes like that often look numerical, but can often be letters as well, I see nothing wrong with that. The important thing to realize is that it is *not* a number, it is a code, you can't sum it, or calculate with it, just use it to identify something, like an SSN.

Comment: I am aware that there are other problems with the query but when I remove that not in clause my performance is much faster.  I'm clearing the cache before each run so I had assumed this was the problem area.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about 'the results don't match up'. Can you give an example of a row that matches when it shouldn't or a row that doesn't match when it should?

Comment: Isn't it always better to use a join instead of an "IN" or "NOT IN"?  I thought that joining would properly use existing indexes while "IN" did not?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a typo, but in the first query, you are comparing the **StuKey** column whereas in the second query you are joining on **Key**

Performance-wise, I'd expect the 2 queries to result in a very similar, if not the same, execution plan. You should check the plans of both to see.

Also, make sure you clear the data cache between runs, as they could actually be performing the same, but due to caching of data, the 2nd appears to be faster.

Comment: the StuKey vs Key was a typo.  Thanks for pointing out.  I thought that using an IN clause caused indexes to not be used properly which is why i moved it to a join.  Am I off base on that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
ser.StuKey not in (select StuKey
```

as compared to:

```
ON ser.key = ser2.key
```

So the rewrite should be:

```
SELECT      ser.key
FROM        dbo.Enrlmt  ser
LEFT JOIN   Enrlmt      ser2
ON          ser.StuKey         = ser2.Stukey
AND         ser.EnrlmtStatCode = ser2.EnrlmtStatCode
AND         ser2.StartDate     > ser.wd
AND         ser2.StartDate     <= @AsOfDate
WHERE       ser.wd             >= @FromDate 
AND         ser.wd             <= @ThrouDate
AND         ser.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321'
AND         ser.StuExitCatgCode in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
AND         ser2.key IS NULL
```

(note I also ucut out the ser2.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321' and rewrote it to a column comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

- NOT EXISTS
- Perhaps no need to correlate `ser2.StartDate > ser.wd` because `ser.wd >= @FromDate`?

Also:

- If you have to use `ser2.StartDate > ser.wd`, are they the same datatype?
- Do all datatypes line up? eg: @FromDate, @ThrouDate, StartDate, wd etc?

thus:

```
Select
    ser.key
From
    dbo.Enrlmt ser     
Where
    ser.wd >= @FromDate AND ser.wd <= @ThrouDate AND
    ser.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321' AND
    ser.StuExitCatgCode in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7') AND
    not EXISTS (select *
                           from Enrlmt ser2 
                          where ser2.StartDate <= @AsOfDate 
                            AND ser2.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321'
                            AND ser2.StartDate > @FromDate --ser.wd??
                            AND ser2.Key = ser.Key)
```

Comment: This answer worked for me in an H2 database. `SELECT C1 FROM T1 WHERE C1 NOT IN (SELECT C1 FROM T2);` didn't return by the time I  canceled it. `SELECT C1 FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT C1 FROM T2);` returns pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good balance between efficiency and clarity:

```
    Select ser.key
From
    dbo.Enrlmt ser
    Left Join (select StuKey 
            from Enrlmt 
            where Enrlmt.StartDate <= @AsOfDate AND 
            Enrlmt.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321') As ser2
    ON ser.key = ser2.key And ser2.StartDate > ser.wd
Where
        ser.wd >= @FromDate AND ser.wd <= @ThrouDate AND
        ser.EnrlmtStatCode = '4321' AND
        ser.StuExitCatgCode in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7') AND
        ser2.key Is Null
```

You might eek out more speed by making the subquery a UDF.  For large amounts of records where the subquery is doing a lot of work, consider putting this all in a UDF or procedure and filling a temporary table with the results of the subquery, using that table in the main query, and then clean up by erasing the temporary table.